# transparent png using wpf in VS2008

Tags: wpf, transactions, png

I want make a UI that is semi transparent in WPF VS2008, so I made my form transparent and I want to show a semi transparent png (Which includes "holes") on top of it.
How do I show the semi transparent png?

Semi transparent, meaning it has holes you can see through.

Also how can I get this done in C#, without using WPF.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should just have to use the Image control and WPF should take care of the rest:

```
<Image Source="myimage.png" />
```

Or in pure C#:

```
BitmapImage sourceImage = new BitmapImage();
sourceImage.BeginInit();
sourceImage.UriSource = new Uri("myimage.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
sourceImage.EndInit();

Image myImage = new Image();
myImage.Source = sourceImage;
```

Comment: hhh, yeah it works.., kinda of a stupid question...
I wonder how you can get this done in C#.

Comment: I want the UI to be transparent, so do I just make a transparent form (HOW?) and put the image on top?

Thanks mate.

Comment: I answered how to make Windows transparent in WPF in this StackOverflow question (vote it up if it helps you): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1541837/how-do-i-make-my-form-transparent-but-what-i-draw-on-it-not