# Simple WPF data binding question with icons

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, binding, treeview

I have a few types that make up a hierarchy like this:

```
+ Image0.Name
    Effect0.Name
    Effect1.Name
    Effect2.Name
    Layer0.Name
    Layer1.Name
    Layer2.Name
    ...
+ Image1.Name
    Effect0.Name
    Effect1.Name
    Effect2.Name
    Layer0.Name
    Layer1.Name
    Layer2.Name
    ...
+ Image2.Name
    Effect0.Name
    Effect1.Name
    Effect2.Name
    Layer0.Name
    Layer1.Name
    Layer2.Name
    ...
```

But I can't get my head around the data binding. Here is the code for the types:

```
public class Image
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Effect> Effects { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Layer> Layers { get; set; }
}

public class Effect
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Effect ( string name )
    {
        this.Name = name;
    }
}

public class Layer
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Layer ( string name )
    {
        this.Name = name;
    }
}

public class EditorView : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    IEnumerable<Node> images;
    public IEnumerable<Node> Images
    {
        get { return images; }
        set
        {
            this.images = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged ( "Images" );
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    void RaisePropertyChanged ( string propertyName )
    {
        var handler = this.PropertyChanged;
        if ( handler != null )
            handler ( this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs ( propertyName ) );
    }
}
```

Additionally these types (`Effect`, `Layer`) has a unique icon per type, if you can also show how to bind this, that would help me a lot in understanding it all.

Comment: Are you binding it to a treeview and will the stucture always be parent and subnodes without expanding more?

Comment: Yep I am binding to a treeview and the structure will always be like that. Currently don't need to go beyond this hierarchy. So always 1 parent, then children, 1 parent, then children, etc.

Comment: Sorry man, I dosed off a bit, let me know if the answer works for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I normally do it, create a base class for the child items and then create I property that returns all the child Items

```
 public class Image 
 { 
    public string Name { get; set;} 
    public IEnumerable<Effect> Effects { get; set; } 
    public IEnumerable<Layer> Layers { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Node> Nodes { get { return ((IEnumerable<Node>)Layers).Union((IEnumerable<Node>)Effects); } }
}

 public class Effect : Node
{
    public Effect(string name) 
    { 
        this.Name = name; 
    } 
}
public class Layer : Node
{ 
      public Layer(string name) { this.Name = name; } 
}

public class Node
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Image Icon { get; set; }
}
```

You should be able to set the Image Property (url of image but you can change the property type) of the respective Effects and Layers and then I've already wired it up, this should work

```
 <TreeView Height="221" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,12,0,0" Name="treeView1" 
              VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="479" ItemsSource="{Binding Images}">
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Nodes}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
                    <Image Source="{Binding Icon}"></Image>
                </StackPanel>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    </TreeView>
```

**EDIT**

And then set the TreeView Item's DataContext to your ViewModel, just as an example I did this in the code behind:

```
Image img = new Image();
Effect effect = new Effect("Effect1");
Layer layer = new Layer("Layer1");
img.Name = "Image1";
List<Effect> effects = new List<Effect>();
effects.Add(effect);
img.Effects = effects;
List<Layer> layers = new List<Layer>();
layers.Add(layer);
img.Layers = layers;
List<WpfApplication1.Image> Images = new List<Image>();
Images.Add(img);
EditorView ev = new EditorView();
ev.Images = Images;
treeView1.DataContext = ev;
```

**EDIT2:** Pasted complete code (without using statements):

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = new EditorView();
    }
}

public class Image 

{ 
    public string Name { get; set;} 
    public IEnumerable<Effect> Effects { get; set; } 
    public IEnumerable<Layer> Layers { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Node> Nodes { get { return ((IEnumerable<Node>)Layers).Union((IEnumerable<Node>)Effects); } }
}
public class Effect : Node
{
    public Effect(string name) 
    { 
        this.Name = name; 
    } 
}
public class Layer : Node
{ 
      public Layer(string name) { this.Name = name; } 
}

public class Node
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Icon { get; set; }
}

public class EditorView : INotifyPropertyChanged 
{
    public EditorView()
    {
        Image img = new Image();
        WpfApplication1.Effect effect = new WpfApplication1.Effect("Effect1");
        WpfApplication1.Layer layer = new Layer("Layer1");
        img.Name = "Image1";
        List<Effect> effects = new List<WpfApplication1.Effect>();
        effects.Add(effect);
        img.Effects = effects;
        List<Layer> layers = new List<Layer>();
        layers.Add(layer);
        img.Layers = layers;
        List<WpfApplication1.Image> Images = new List<Image>();
        Images.Add(img);
        this.Images = Images;
    }

    IEnumerable<Image> images;
    public IEnumerable<Image> Images 
    { 
        get 
    { 
            return images; 
    } 
        set { this.images = value; this.RaisePropertyChanged("Images"); 
        } 
    } public event 
        PropertyChangedEventHandler 
        PropertyChanged; 
    void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName) 
    { var handler = this.PropertyChanged; 
        if (handler != null)            

            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName)); 
    } 
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks man, I will let you know asap when I try this. Thanks again.

Comment: I just tried it but couldn't figure out the viewmodel class you used? Did you use similar to `EditorView`? Because I don't see a container class name, only contained property names like `.Nodes`, etc.

Comment: I tried `<HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding EditorView.Nodes}">` but didn't work.

Comment: Ok, I've added some example code for you, I've used your EditorView Exactly

Comment: Thanks, I tried that one specifically `treeView1.DataContext = ev;` at the end (after I initialize ev, etc, but it threw a null exception. But I put the `ev` inside the MainWindow class as a property. Does that matter? Also what would that DataContext line would look like if it was in xaml? `DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"`?

Comment: Thanks I got it working now. I set the data context of the window to `        DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"`, and it shows now. Thanks man, I understand it now. So for the icons, do you know if I can have transparency/alpha? Also is having a path enough or should I preload it? I could preload it to make it faster.

Comment: Ok, didn't realize you wanted to use EditorView as your viewmodel. You can then actually set the form's DataContext to EditorView and not just the TreeView, that is how mvvm normally works. If you want to bind to a property it needs to be a dependency property, I will update the code and paste my complete sample

Comment: Cool, glad it works, I suggest having a look at a mvvm library like mvvmlight, really easy to get a hang of and makes life alot easier!

Comment: In terms of the Icons, I am sure you should be able to use transparency (haven't personally used that before). With regards to the images I would preload it

Comment: Thanks man, appreciate it. Btw I also get this error printed in the output. Do you know how to fix it? It happens when I expand the treeview items, and at the startup: `System.Windows.Data Error: 1 : Cannot create default converter to perform 'one-way' conversions between types 'System.Windows.Controls.Image' and 'System.Windows.Media.ImageSource'. Consider using Converter property of Binding. BindingExpression:Path=Icon; DataItem='Node' (HashCode=66306328); target element is 'Image' (Name=''); target property is 'Source' (type 'ImageSource')`

Comment: ImageSource should actually be a string, my bad, wasn't thinking, then set the string to the sourcepath

Comment: Have a look at this article if you want to preload them into a resource and then use a valueconverter to find the image: http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2010/07/23/bind-an-image-to-a-property-in-wpf/

Comment: Thanks man, I will change it now. So Icon is of type string, right? Your article seems useful, will use it. Lastly do you know if this supports transparency? I will use png as it can have transparency.

Comment: Sorry, had to go last night, yip, Icon should be the relative path of your Image file or have a look here for resource file (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1608417/transparent-png-using-wpf-in-vs2008). Wpf does support alpha/transparent images so you should be fine

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement the **HierarchicalDataTemplate**. For sample of it look at the last of this article - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx and this one - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chkoenig/archive/2008/05/24/hierarchical-databinding-in-wpf.aspx